# androidアプリのjavadoc出力時に、android標準ライブラリを対象外にする方法が知りたい

Tags: java, android

Android StudioのGenerate JavaDocでjavadocを出力しようとしています。
すると、「エラー: パッケージandroid.contentは存在しません」や「エラー: パッケージandroid.utilは存在しません」のようなandroid標準ライブラリが見つからないというエラーがでます。
そこで、javadoc出力時に、android標準ライブラリを対象外にする方法が知りたいです。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520220/android-studio-fails-to-read-packages-while-generating-javadoc/25521998 を試してみると良いかも知れません。